# Can we connect to Cassandra using cluster name and not IP address?

Tags: cassandra

My Cassandra cluster name is: "Test Cluster"
It has three nodes with three separate IPs.
I am able to connect using the IP and password.

I need to know if there is a possible way to connect using Cluster Name and not IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use only cluster name - driver need somehow to find at least one node to connect to cluster.  You can use host name although, not IP, and then driver will discover the other nodes in the cluster after connection to any node of the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your node using your hostname or IP address from the CQLSH. Generally we connect locally without IP if your node resolves the hostname and you configured /etc/hosts

You cannot connect using Cluster name in Cassandra.